# echo --version doesn't works

Tags: linux, echo

how can i know version of echo command
as specified in the man page for echo
echo --version should output version of echo command
is it a bug in echo command or its documentation..
plz explain..
same is the case with echo help!!

Comment: Please include a link to the man page that claims `echo --version` does anything other than write "--version" to stdout.

Comment: @S.Lott - try /bin/echo --version :)

Comment: Why vote to close this? Builtin precedence can be highly confusing for people just starting to write (portable) shell scripts.

Comment: If You are satisfied with the provided answer, please mark it as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are probably hitting the shell builtin `echo`. Try using the real program

```
/bin/echo --version
```

For a help section of the builtin echo, try

```
help echo
```

And for its manpage, try

```
man bash
```

If you are using the bash as your shell

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the echo you use is the one intergrated in bash.

```
/bin/echo --version
```

will force calling the echo from coreutils, and show its version.

Answer (score 0):

For more information on "builtins" check the builtins man page (bash specific, basically the "builtins" section of the main, extensive bash man page)

Comment: how can i force the shell.. to use the normal echo program instead of the shell builtin..
the shell first looks up for builtins before searching this in path environment variable..
How can I bypass this step??

thanx..